# Cannot import css files (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, path

When I try to import css files from components, an error occurs.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/HeaderTemplate.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './styles/HeaderTemplate.css' in '/workspace/test/myapp/src/components'
```

I think there's an error in the path, but I don't know how to change it, so I'm asking.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go up one level when importing:

```
import styles from '../styles/HeaderTemplate.css'
```